# Convert finite intersection of countable unions into countable union of finite intersections

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, infinity

Let $(A_m^{(n)})$ be a sequence of sets indexed by $m$ and $n$. Let $$\Delta \triangleq \bigcap_{n=1}^N \bigcup_{m=1}^\infty A_m^{(n)}.$$

From the identity $(a+b)(c+d) = ac+ad+bc+cd$, I guess $\Delta$ can be written as a countable union, i.e., $$\Lambda = \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb N^N} \bigcap_{n=1}^N A_{k_n}^{(n)},$$ where $k_n$ is the $n$-th coordinate of the multi-index $k \in \mathbb N^N$.

---

I would like to ask if my proof is correct and if below statement is correct, i.e.,

> Countable intersection of countable unions can be written as countable union of countable intersections.

Of course, if $N = \mathbb N$, then $\mathbb N^N$ is uncountable.

---

**Proof:** For $x \in \Delta$, $x \in \bigcup_{m=1}^\infty A_m^{(n)}$ for all $n$. Then for each $n$, there is some $k_n$ such that $x \in A_{k_n}^{(n)}$. Hence $x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^N A_{k_n}^{(n)}$ and thus $x \in \Lambda$.

For $x \in \Lambda$, $x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^N A_{k_n}^{(n)}$ for some $k = (k_1, \ldots,k_N) \in \mathbb N^N$. Then $x \in A_{k_n}^{(n)}$ for all $n$. Hence $ x \in \bigcup_{m=1}^\infty A_m^{(n)}$ for all $n$ and thus $x \in \Delta$.

Comment: It is correct and it does generalize to infinite intersections of infinite unions.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy If $N =\mathbb N$, then $\mathbb N^N$ is uncountable.

Comment: Yes it is. @KaviRamaMurthy is pointing out that in general, for any cardinal $\kappa$, there's an analogous identity between a $\kappa$-ary intersection of (say) countable unions, and countable unions of $\kappa$-ary intersections. And yes, you can change "countable" to "$\lambda$-ary" for $\lambda$ a cardinal other than $\aleph_0$.

Comment: @BrianO So if $\kappa = \aleph_0$, then the $\kappa$-array is no more countable?

Comment: That's right. In that case, the union of intersections is taken over $\mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ the set of all functions $k \colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, which has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$. The identity is $$\Lambda = \bigcup_{k \in \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}} \bigcap_{n\in \mathbb{N}} A_{k(n)}^{(n)}$$.

Comment: Thank you so much @BrianO.